# What do you call a bug that occurs once and hardly occurs again or you are not able to reproduce it?

Tags: nomenclature

Some "mysterious" bugs occur once, and then they either never occur or occur after months or years. You are not able to reproduce them because you don't know why they happen. Is there a technical name for such bugs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This kind of bug is usually referred to as a [Heisenbug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug).

Comment: I think "Heisenbug" is specific to a "bug that seems to disappear or alter its behavior when one attempts to study it," to quote the Wikipedia article you linked to, which is subtly different than a bug that is simply rare or has no known reproduction steps. If a bug is simply hard to reproduce, I like "intermittent" as suggested by @yuriy-galanter.

Comment: This is not a Heisenbug. A Heisenbug in the definition has to do with, by attempting to use a debugger or adding print statements changes the execution of the code in such a way making the bug more difficult or impossible to find. If you have a source that follows this definition, please feel free to share! But otherwise it doesn't match the wikipedia definition (which I am not claiming to be "THE" source of truth). I was also looking for a definition that OP is looking for... but the best term I can come up with is like the other commenter's or, "sporadic" would be another alternative term.